# php error coding to utf8 a text extracted from pdf

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, text, utf-8

I need to extract a text in a php variable from a pdf file, i used pdf2text for this, but i have problems when i try to convert the string to utf-8 target.

Also if someone knows a better way to delete the spaces and line breacks of the string, i would be grateful.

this is the code i have used:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

mb_http_output('UTF-8');

include('pdftophp.php');
$doc = new PDF2Text();
$doc->setFilename('pdf/prueba.pdf'); 
$doc->decodePDF();
$texto = $doc->output();

$resultado = "";
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($texto) ; $i++) { 
    if (substr($texto,$i,1) != " " && substr($texto,$i,1) != "\n"){
        $resultado.= substr($texto,$i,1);
    }
}

echo $resultado;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on _have problems_. If you'd provide the string which cases problems it would easier to debug - please take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Try to use `utf8_encode($resultado)` or `utf8_decode($resultado)` on echo.

Comment: i have tried it, but if the string have tildes or special characters, 
Those are replaced by interrogations